# Rmarkdown read_chunk and cross reference

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I have a `plots.R` file which has following format

```
## ---- t1-1 ------
plot(pressure)

## --- t2-1 ---
summary(pressure)
```

I am reading this file via knitr::read_chunk in another Rmarkdown file named `force.Rmd`. Problem is I want to cross reference it? How can I do that when the chunk label is same as in plots.R

format of `force.Rmd` file is

```
`{r}
knitr::read_chunk(plots.R
`

`{r t1-1,echo=F}
`
```

I want to cross reference this chunk as `/@ref(fig:t1-1)` but this is not working since the chunk label is the same in `plots.R`. I am using bookdown package in `force.Rmd` file in YAML header with fig_caption: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to cross-reference figures in bookdown, the figure has to be put in a figure environment to generate the figure number. I believe this requires the figure to have a caption, which is generated with the `fig.cap='string'` option for that code chunk.

Comment: May be there is some bug. I had two figures under t1-1 originally in plots.R. When i deleted one it has worked now. Thanks